# Decreasing counter has bizarre behaviour

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm building a counter with setInterval who decreases the time every second, works for the first few seconds, then get stuck and increases and decreases at the same time.

In my case i start it 5:00 (m:ss) and after a few seconds blocks arround 4:49 and start increasing then decreasing...

not sure what is gooing on.

```
start = () => {
        console.log('starting')
        let timeLeft = this.state.totalDuration
        setInterval(() => {
            if (timeLeft > 0) {
                timeLeft = (timeLeft - 1000)
                this.setState({ totalDuration: timeLeft })
            }
        }, 1000)
    }



 render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Timer interval={this.state.totalDuration}></Timer>
                <ButtonsRow>
                    <RoundButton title='Reset' color='white' background='grey'></RoundButton>
                    <RoundButton onPress={this.start()} title='Start' color='white' background='red'></RoundButton>
                </ButtonsRow>
</View>
```

Comment: It's not solution for your problem but you should `clearInterval` if `timeLeft` is <= 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are capturing the `timeLeft` variable in a closure outside the interval function. So it gets captured once when start is pressed and remains the same value afterwards. Instead use the `setState` variant that accepts callback.

```
start = () => {
        console.log('starting')
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
             this.setState(state => { 
                  if (state.totalDuration > 0) 
                    return { totalDuration : state.totalDuration - 1000 }
                  else {
                    clearInterval(interval)
                    return {}
                  }
              })
        }, 1000)
    }
```